# If a series of reals is convergent, must the series of their cubes also be convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a series of reals is convergent, must the series of their cubes also be convergent? I don't think so, but I can't seem to find a counter-example.

Answer (score 5):

divide terms of your series into triples and let the n-th triple be $\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}, \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}, \frac{-2}{n^{1/3}}$ it's easy to see that's a counterxample

Comment: For further consideration, do you have a guess as to the conclusion if the original series is absolutely convergent?

Comment: then the series of cubes is also absolutely convergent since for $n$ sufficiently large $|a_n| < 1$ and so $|a_n^3| \leq |a_n|$